# How do you sum a scripted field using Python's elasticsearch_dsl Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, python-3.6, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

This works for me correctly:

```
search = Search(using=client, index='my_index').script_fields(
    special={'script': {
        'source': "<a formula that produces a double>"}
    }
)
```

And now I want to attach a sum the field `special` across all hits. I tried this:

```
search = Search(using=client, index='my_index').script_fields(
    special={'script': {
        'source': "<a formula that produces a double>"}
    }
).aggs.metric('total', 'sum', field='special')
```

But when I check the `aggs` attibute of the response, I get

```
{'total': {'value': 0.0}}
```

The response itself tells me that `special` is populated correctly for each entry, and it's always positive. It looks a bit to me like `special` might not be around at the time the sum occurs, so that elasticsearch doesn't see it and so it makes a sum of `0`. I experimented with `pipeline` in place of `metric` but that didn't change things. What I'm proposing should be possible, right?

I could do the sum in my script rather than through elasticsearch, but I'm betting the sum on the ES side will be much faster.

---

Update

Based on [this discussion at elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/aggregation-not-working-on-scripted-field/99430) I think I found the way it's supposed to work, but it still isn't working properly for me. You provide the script inside the aggregation like this:

```
s=Search(using=client, index='my_index').aggs.pipeline('total', 'sum', script={'source': "<the special formula>"})
```

The problem now is that the output is not correct. On a test index with one item of a given time, I tried to report that field in the sum aggregation, and instead of the expected result (the value of the field) I got something that was different by 128.

---

Update

I received an answer to this last problem in the elasticsearch help forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/script-aggregation-yields-wrong-but-close-answer/133744/3?u=rschwieb

In a nutshell, the data stored in the field was interpreted as a double by elasticsearch, but the aggregation used the type determined by the mapping for the index (which said 'float' instead). After re-indexing the field as a double, the numbers are as expected.